# Django 1.10 using old version of static file with DjangoManifest

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles

I'm using Django Manifest to manage my static files version.
When I'm updating a static file (CSS or JS), the staticfiles.json is being updated but Django keeps using the old version.
I'm working with Amazon S3 and Cloudfront CDN.

Something I noticed is that it always uses the last version before the latest one. Therefore, I can change just a bit in the file and collect static files again in order to update it, but that's annoying...

This is my custom storage class:

```
class StaticStorage(ManifestFilesMixin, S3BotoStorage):
    """uploads to 'mybucket/static/', serves from 'cloudfront.net/static/'"""
    location = settings.STATICFILES_LOCATION

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['custom_domain'] = settings.AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN
        super(StaticStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thanks!
Rani

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just executing collectstatic before starting the server...
As simple as that :(